# OpenLayers Point Geometry never resizes

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

My website contains an OpenStreetMaps. I use OpenLayers to place a Geometry.Point on top of a city.

A button allows the user to resize this point, but it is never resized and I can't understand why.

Here is my code :

```
var button = document.myform.btClear,
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("map_element", {}),
    osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(),
    vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(),
    fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
    position = new OpenLayers.LonLat(6.9673223,50.9572449).transform(fromProjection, toProjection),
    point =  new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(6.9673223,50.9572449).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);

map.addLayer(osm);
map.addLayer(vectors);
map.setCenter(position, 5);

pointFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point);
vectors.addFeatures([pointFeature]);

button.onclick = function() {
    vectors.features[0].geometry.resize(1.5, point);
    vectors.redraw();
};
```

Can you help me to figure it out ?

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/39KE5/1/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with OpenLayers much, so take everything here with a grain of salt. I was looking at this example (http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/resize-features.html), and I think the geometry resize does something different than what you're intending. I think what you really want to change is the style of the point. I've modified your fiddle as an example, at http://jsfiddle.net/MLundin617/39KE5/2/. It's not complete, as the click also manages to change the color of the point, but I believe it's closer to what you're looking for.

This is the major change:

```
radius = 2
button.onclick = function() {
    radius = radius * 1.5
    vectors.features[0].style = {pointRadius: radius}
    vectors.redraw();
};
```

(Also, in your jsFiddle, you were referencing the incorrect form element, so the onclick couldn't be defined.)

Let me know if that helps. Curious to see any other answers as well.

Comment: In the example, note that the size of the point never actually changes.